# How to find out what class is referenced the most?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, intellij-idea

How to find out what class is referenced the most?

I want to find the most important classes in a large system and i think that is the best way to do it. any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe the [JDepend](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) is what you looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the [Metrics plugin](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/) can do it? I haven’t tried it, but on the home page it mentions two coupling metrics and shows pretty graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Use VisualVM and then go to Sampler -> Memory and you will see a graph as below representing the number of instances (not exactly the reference number):

Alternatively you can use some Eclipse plugins (I use [inCode](http://www.intooitus.com/products/incode)) or [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org) for statically obtaining the reference count.

[image]

Comment: which is accesible via java_home/bin/jvisualvm

Answer (score 1):

Another similar tool [CodePro - Dependency Analysis](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/dependencies/dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Netbeans Profiler tools.

If you choose the **Memory mode** you will be able to know Live Bytes /Live Objects / Allocated Objects and more per classes.

I think this way you can find out the classes you use the more or that use the more memory.

You have to run the app to know the results I don't know if your looking for a "static" way.